# PyCharm "не видит" переменную, определенную с помощью сквозного присваивания

Tags: python, pycharm

Коллеги, обнаружил странность в PyCharm с оператором сквозного присваивания `:=`. Возьмем какой-то вот такой код:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lst[ind := 5] += lst[ind + 2]
print(lst)
```

Вот как он выглядит в PyCharm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данное выражение является синтаксически верным и ошибки не содержит, но, как видим, PyCharm считает, что второе вхождение `ind` является `Unresolved reference 'ind'`, что **должно привести к исключению**. Однако, несмотря на это, **код отрабатывает без ошибок** с ожидаемым результатом.

**Вопрос**

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Это только мой PyCharm или у всех? Исправляется ли в настройках?

*Специально накатил самую последнюю версию PyCharm - не помогло*